# local json file not found when it is actually there

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code

```
var jpath = "bank-holidays.json";
          $.getJSON(jpath, function (ukdata) {...});
```

But I am getting a 404 file not found, even though the file is there.

Comment: When you look at the request in the console is the path what you expect?

Comment: Yes, the calling page is in the root, the json file is also in the root

Comment: GET http://localhost:50009/bank-holidays.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check the file name. Is your server configured to serve static files? There are so many unknowns that we can't really help you. Or rather, it's probably a problem with your server setup, not your client side code.

Comment: Will your server server up that file if you browse to it directly?

Comment: And the server is set up to serve .json files? What is the server you are running?

Comment: have you checked the mime type on your web server? can you open the file if you call it directly in the browser?

Comment: hmm no, seems I have a MIME issue

Comment: As I asked 15 minutes ago...what server are you using?

Comment: is it because you are using "bank-holidays.json" rather then a relative or absolute url? Normally i use "/scripts/bank-holidays.json" or similar

Comment: @eg_dac That is a relative url... Problem is the server is not set up to serve that file type.

Comment: no shit. i am saying often people leave out the "/" or "./" which then points to the wrong level of directory.

Comment: also you could try to name your file .js then you won't have mime type issues.

Comment: It was the mime type, I added that to the web.config and it now works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file to bank-holidays.text. If it works correctly, you should add a .json MIME type of 'application/json' and rename the file again.

If this solution not work with you then you saved the file in a wrong format, try to create a new JSON file and make sure it's a json and it hadn't have a wrong association